# How to redirect all admin pages in Magento to another domain and subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess, magento, syntax

I'm attempting to Redirect all `.htaccess` keeping administration on a Magento site. I found this coding example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php/admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/new/ [NC]
RewriteRule !^new/ /new%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

...but can't seem to get the syntax right.

For argument's sake, let's call the site I'm editing `www.example.ca`.

I'm trying to redirect everything but `www.example**.ca**/admin` to `www.example**.com**/landing` – but keep failing.

Can someone please give me a snippet of code with proper syntax using the example URLs above?

Comment: so why not just `rewritecond %{request_uri} !^/admin` and `rewriterule (.*) /new$1`? First one excludes /admin urls, the other one then rewrites everything else.

Comment: Marc: Thank you for responding! 

I'm not knowledgeable enough to understand it... but would love to try your elegant looking solution. Can you please give me a snippet using the URL examples above?

Thanks again!

Comment: what does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Jon if all paths to go `/landing`, you will get a `404 not found` error unless `/landing` is the name of a script that can handle all requests. If there is no file on the server with that name, what do you want to happen?

Comment: Thanks, @BeetleJuice – the landing page is on a .com domain, whereas the site I'm attempting to redirect (except /admin) is all on a .ca domain. I should have highlighted that somehow in the original post.

Comment: So if I enter `example.ca/page1.html`, `...page2.html`..., you want me redirected to `example.com/landing` right?  If everyone is going to `/landing` does it mean you don't really care which exact location (pag1 vs page2) the user was redirected from?

Comment: @BeetleJuice - Exactly. Other than /admin (which I need to keep access to for a bit) any page a visitor enters from on .ca should be redirected to .com/landing.

Comment: @Forbs - It was a 'suggested tag'. Sorry. Removed.

Comment: Understood I think. Try my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Folks. After WAY more googling AND trial and error than I care to admit... I found this bit of code did the trick.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/landing [R=302,L]
```

Thanks to everyone for helping get me on the right track – appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Jon, does this work for you?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)           http://example.com/landing    [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @BeetleJuice – SO CLOSE! Everything on the .ca domain is now redirecting to the .com landing page... including /admin, unfortunately. Any suggestions?